# Issue with Migrating From PHP SQL queries To MySQL Stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, migration

I require to migrate all the SQL queries from PHP to Stored procedures

I'm facing issues with the syntax while migrating, for instance, an array, for each loop, join, implode functions needs to be converted into stored procedures

```
<?php

$id = $this->user->info->ID;
$friendQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT u.ID, u.username FROM users u WHERE u.ID 
                            IN (SELECT u1.ID FROM users u1 
                            WHERE u1.ID IN (SELECT uf.friendid FROM user_friends uf WHERE uf.status = '2' AND uf.userid = '".$id."' ) 
                            OR u1.ID IN (SELECT uf2.userid FROM user_friends uf2 WHERE uf2.status = '2' AND uf2.friendid = '".$id."') AND u1.ID != '".$id."' ) 
                            ")->result_array();

foreach($friendQuery as $key => $fof) {

    $fofQuery[$fof['username']] = $this->db->query("SELECT u.ID FROM users u WHERE u.`ID` NOT IN ('".$id."') AND u.ID 
            IN (SELECT u1.ID FROM users u1 
            WHERE u1.ID IN (SELECT uf.friendid FROM user_friends uf WHERE uf.status = '2' AND uf.userid = '".$fof['ID']."' AND uf.friendid != '".$fof['ID']."') 
            OR u1.ID IN (SELECT uf2.userid FROM user_friends uf2 WHERE uf2.status = '2' AND uf2.friendid = '".$fof['ID']."' AND uf2.userid != '".$fof['ID']."') AND u1.ID != '".$fof['ID']."' ) 
            ")->result_array();

} 
$final_array = array();

foreach($fofQuery as $arr){
    foreach($arr as $a){
        $final_array[$a['ID']] = $a['ID'];
    }
}
$FoFData = array_values($final_array);

foreach($FoFData as $fa){
    $commaList[] = join(',', (array) $fa);
}

$result = implode(",", $commaList);
$data = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT ft.ID as ID, ft.userid, ft.content, ft.timestamp, ft.likes, ft.comments, u.username, u.avatar, ft.friend_id, ft.friend_username, feed_item_setting.*  
                FROM feed_item ft
                LEFT JOIN users u ON ft.userid = u.ID
                JOIN `feed_item_setting` ON `feed_item_setting`.`user_id` = u.id
                WHERE ft.userid = u.ID AND u.ID IN (".$result.",".$id.") ORDER BY ft.ID DESC")->result_array();
```

I have partially converted the above code of snippets into the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `SomeDB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetFeedSetting`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `GetFeedSetting` (IN `feed_setting_user_id` BIGINT) READS SQL DATA DETERMINISTIC SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  DECLARE flag VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE v_read_setting_status,
          v_write_setting_status,
          v_write_cmt_setting_status,
          v_like_setting_status INT(11);
  SELECT
    `read_status`,
    `write_status`,
    `write_cmt_status`,
    `like_status` 
  INTO v_read_setting_status,
    `v_write_setting_status`,
    `v_write_cmt_setting_status`,
    `v_like_setting_status`
  FROM `feed_item_setting`
  WHERE `user_id` = feed_setting_user_id;

  IF (v_read_setting_status = 3) THEN
    SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u` 
    WHERE `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = feed_setting_user_id) 
    OR 
        `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`friendid` = feed_setting_user_id)
    OR
        `u`.`ID` = feed_setting_user_id;


  ELSE
    SET flag = 'failure';
  END IF;

  SELECT flag;
END$$


DELIMITER ;
```

As I'm facing problems with an array iterating in the foreach loop and some inbuilt PHP functions such as with join, implode needs to be converted into stored procedures

---

**Update:**

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `someDB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AddFeedFriendItemsMod`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddFeedFriendItemsMod`(IN `senderid` BIGINT(255), IN `friendid` BIGINT(255), IN `friendusername` VARCHAR(255), IN `keyword` TEXT)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

        DECLARE v_read_setting_status, v_write_setting_status, v_write_cmt_setting_status,  v_like_setting_status INT(11);
        DECLARE LastFeedId INT;
        DECLARE flag VARCHAR(255);
        INSERT INTO feed_item (`userid`, `content`, `timestamp`, `likes`, `comments`, `user_flag`, `likes_data`, `friend_id`, `friend_username`)
        VALUES (senderid, keyword, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 0, 0, 0, 'like', friendid, friendusername);
        SET LastFeedId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT INTO feed_item_likes (`feed_item_id`, `user_id`, `timestamp`, `is_like`)
        VALUES (LastFeedId, senderid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 0);
        SELECT LastFeedId;


        SELECT `read_status`, `write_status`, `write_cmt_status`, `like_status` INTO v_read_setting_status, `v_write_setting_status`, `v_write_cmt_setting_status`, `v_like_setting_status`
        FROM `feed_item_setting`
        WHERE `user_id` = friendid;

        IF (v_write_setting_status = 0) THEN
            SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u` WHERE 
            `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = friendid  ) 
            OR 
            `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`friendid` = friendid )
            OR
            `u`.`ID` = friendid;

        ELSEIF (v_write_setting_status = 1) THEN
            SELECT `ID` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`ID`= friendid;

        ELSEIF (v_write_setting_status = 2) THEN
            SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u` WHERE 
            `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = friendid  ) 
            OR 
            `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`friendid` = friendid )
            OR
            `u`.`ID` = friendid;

        ELSEIF (v_write_setting_status = 3) THEN

            DECLARE friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u`  
                WHERE `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM users `u1` 
                WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN 
                (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM user_friends `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = friendid ) 
                OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = friendid) 
                AND `u1`.`ID` != friendid);

            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS unique_tbl; #precaution: when sp stops with error 
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE unique_tbl (user_id BIGINT UNIQUE); #to avoid duplicate added unique

            INSERT INTO unique_tbl VALUES (friendid); # added input from sp

                OPEN friend_cursor;
                friend_loop: LOOP

                FETCH friend_cursor INTO v_friendID;

                IF exit_loop THEN
                    LEAVE friend_loop;
                ELSE

                    REPLACE INTO unique_tbl VALUES (v_friendID); # since we need all unique id's using replace if exists

                    fof: BEGIN

                    DECLARE friend_of_friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 
                        SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u` WHERE `u`.`ID` NOT IN (friendid) AND `u`.`ID` 
                        IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM `users` `u1` 
                        WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = v_friendID AND `uf`.`friendid` != v_friendID) 
                        OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = v_friendID AND `uf2`.`userid` != v_friendID) 
                        AND `u1`.`ID` != v_friendID );

                    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop1 = TRUE;

                    OPEN friend_of_friend_cursor;
                    friend_of_friend_loop: LOOP

                        FETCH friend_of_friend_cursor INTO FoFID;

                        IF exit_loop1 THEN
                        LEAVE friend_of_friend_loop;
                        END IF;

                        REPLACE INTO unique_tbl VALUES (FoFID);

                    END LOOP friend_of_friend_loop;
                    CLOSE friend_of_friend_cursor;
                    END;
                END IF;
                END LOOP friend_loop;
                CLOSE friend_cursor;

            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM unique_tbl; #this will show result in comma seperated 2,34,56,78

            #cleanup
            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS unique_tbl;

        ELSEIF (v_write_setting_status = 4) THEN
            SELECT `ID` FROM `users`;

        ELSE
            SELECT `ID` FROM `users`;
        END IF;




    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Actual Result:**

```
Query: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddFeedFriendItemsMod`(IN `senderid` BIGINT(255), IN `friendid` BIGINT(255), IN `fr...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u`  
        ' at line 43
```

Getting Error w.r.t (v_write_setting_status = 3) block.

Comment: Are you sure you want to move **all** logic to MySQL? Why not use prepared statements solely to gather data and PHP to handle it?

Comment: Yes, I required to move all the logic which is in MySQL to stored procedure via Node.JS. Because intermediate Node should retrieve the ID with some other data altogether @NicoHaase

Comment: I could help you, but i don't have idea about php, so if you explain in which part of sql you need help, let me know.

Comment: Assigning multiple values to variables and iterating over via `ForEach` @James

Comment: `foreach` which is php way of expression but in mysql we don't have that.

Comment: `foreach` = `while` + `count` . We need to traverse all the elements within a loop so count with while is sufficed or any other idea. Answer if you know partially with the above snippets posted. So once when we get actual result with migration we could edit your answer @James

Comment: does your condition satisfies by using cursor? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cursors.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196471/discussion-between-nishanth--and-james).

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `someDB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AAB`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `AAB`(IN `feed_setting_user_id` BIGINT)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
DECLARE v_friendID, FoFID BIGINT; # use datatype which is used for u.ID used int based on ur result
DECLARE exit_loop, exit_loop1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 

    SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u`  
    WHERE `u`.`ID` IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM users `u1` 
    WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM user_friends `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = feed_setting_user_id ) 
    OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = feed_setting_user_id) 
    AND `u1`.`ID` != feed_setting_user_id); 

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS unique_tbl; #precaution: when sp stops with error 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE unique_tbl (user_id BIGINT UNIQUE); #to avoid duplicate added unique

INSERT INTO unique_tbl VALUES (feed_setting_user_id); # added input from sp

    OPEN friend_cursor;
    friend_loop: LOOP

        FETCH friend_cursor INTO v_friendID;

        IF exit_loop THEN
            LEAVE friend_loop;
        ELSE

            REPLACE INTO unique_tbl VALUES (v_friendID); # since we need all unique id's using replace if exists

            fof: BEGIN

                DECLARE friend_of_friend_cursor CURSOR FOR 


                    SELECT `u`.`ID` FROM `users` `u` WHERE `u`.`ID` NOT IN (feed_setting_user_id) AND `u`.`ID` 
            IN (SELECT `u1`.`ID` FROM `users` `u1` 
            WHERE `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf`.`friendid` FROM `user_friends` `uf` WHERE `uf`.`status` = '2' AND `uf`.`userid` = v_friendID AND `uf`.`friendid` != v_friendID) 
            OR `u1`.`ID` IN (SELECT `uf2`.`userid` FROM `user_friends` `uf2` WHERE `uf2`.`status` = '2' AND `uf2`.`friendid` = v_friendID AND `uf2`.`userid` != v_friendID) 
            AND `u1`.`ID` != v_friendID ); 

                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop1 = TRUE;

                OPEN friend_of_friend_cursor;
                friend_of_friend_loop: LOOP

                    FETCH friend_of_friend_cursor INTO FoFID;

                    IF exit_loop1 THEN
                        LEAVE friend_of_friend_loop;
                    END IF;

                    REPLACE INTO unique_tbl VALUES (FoFID);

                END LOOP friend_of_friend_loop;
                CLOSE friend_of_friend_cursor;
                SET exit_loop1 = FALSE; 
            END;
        END IF;
    END LOOP friend_loop;
    CLOSE friend_cursor;
    SET exit_loop = FALSE;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM unique_tbl; #this will show result in comma seperated 2,34,56,78

#cleanup
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS unique_tbl;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```